# Windows 7 system left in unusable state after moving system partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, gparted

I tried doing some PC maintenance on my home computer last night, and hosed it up.

A couple years ago i installed a 120GB SSD in my PC. I partitioned it into two equal partitions, the first being my system drive for Windows Server 2008 R2 and the second my Windows 7 system drive.

However, I soon decided that I did not have enough usable space, so I went back to using a HDD as the system drive for my 2008 machine, and continued using the 2nd partition of my SSD as the system drive for my Win 7 install.

I finally decided that I wanted to expand the Win7 partition to use the whole drive.

Since expanding a partition to the "left" is not possible from the Windows disk maangement tool i used GParted to copy the 2nd partition onto the first, then deleted the 2nd partition.

I then I had to use my win7 installation disc to repair windows startup.

Unfortunately, now Win7 boots in an unusable state.

It boots to the login screen ok, but after I authenticate explorer fails to launch leaving me with a blank blue background. If I try to run explorer.exe from task manager i get an error.

Can I recover from this without reinstalling Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling Windows. Of course, I copied my data to a different drive first.